# If variable contains variable then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, query-string, contains

I have an if statement to generate active classes, it works in most cases but I have an admin section where you can access the front-end products but the URL changes to use query strings to get the correct page.

For this reason, I am trying to create an if statement to say, if VariableHREF contains variableQueryString then do something...

```
if(variableHREF contains variableQueryString ){
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
}
```

I have that at the minute but it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Did you try `indexOf()`

Comment: `if(variableHREF.indexOf(variableQueryString) > -1 ){...}`

Comment: Could I have something like this: variableHREF.indexOf(variableQueryString)>0

Comment: Check for `-1`, not `0` or use `>= 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(variableHREF.indexOf(variableQueryString) >= 0){
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
}
```

Should do the trick for you.